# convertir un string a un objeto

Tags: javascript, funciones, objeto

Quiero convertir este string a un objeto y contar las palabras que se repiten menos el que tiene _

```
var var1 = `hola chao pelota _juega hola chao peluche`;

el outcome deberia ser 

var1 = {
hola:2,
chao:2,
peluche:1
}
```

intente con JSON.parse pero no funciona por el formato del string

Answer (score 0):

se hace un filtro y luego con la funcion reduce se saca el total

```
var1.split(' ').filter(char => char[0] !== '_')
const words = var1.split(' ').filter(char => char[0] !== '_')
const filterWords=  words.reduce((acc,curr) => {
                    acc[curr] = ++acc[curr] || 1; 
                    return acc;} ,{})
```

Comment: Hola, podrias ayudarme a entneder como utilizaste reduce? y el output esta bien solo que la propiedad balon la vuelve string